# How do I give a command multiple numbers and output multiple objects R

Tags: r, command

I want to do something like

```
range <- c(1,100,250, 500, 1000)
hdbscan_object{1:5} <- hdbscan(DF1, minPts = range)
```

Instead of:

```
hdbscan_object1 <- hdbscan(DF1, minPts = 1)
hdbscan_object2 <- hdbscan(DF1, minPts = 100)
hdbscan_object3 <- hdbscan(DF1, minPts = 250)
hdbscan_object4 <- hdbscan(DF1, minPts = 500)
hdbscan_object5 <- hdbscan(DF1, minPts = 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `list2env`.  Loop over the 'range' vector with `lapply`, apply the function, store the output in a `list` ('lst1'), name the `list` and use `list2env` to create those objects in the global env

```
lst1 <- lapply(range, function(x) hdbscan(DF1, minPts = x))
names(lst1) <- paste0("hdbscan_object", seq_along(lst1))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or another option is `assign` in a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(range)) {
     assign(paste0("hdbscan_object", i), 
           hdbscan(DF1, minPts = range[i]))
  }
```

Comment: Trying ``lst1 <- lapply(range, function(x) hdbscan(DF1, minPts = x))`` gives me ``Error: unexpected symbol in "lst1 <- lapply(range, function(x) hdbscan(Pruned_PCA_PC1_4, minPts = x) names"`` and showing the trace back shows ``Error in dbscan::kNN(x, k, sort = TRUE, ...) : Illegal k: needs to be k>=1! `` I think this means that wont work with the hdbscan command?

Comment: @SkyScraper that must be an issue with the `range` values.  I tried with the inbuilt data and have the same error `hdbscan(moons, minPts = 1)#
Error in dbscan::kNN(x, k, sort = TRUE, ...) : 
  Illegal k: needs to be k>=1!`

Comment: @SkyScraper from the eg. `hdbscan(moons, minPts = 5)` works.  So, if I use these values, it is working fine `lapply(c(5, 10), function(x) hdbscan(moons, minPts = x))`

Comment: On a related note, would you know how to get something like this to work: ``ggplot(DF1, aes(x=X, y=Y, color=as.factor(paste0("hbdscan_object", "1","$cluster")))) + geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6)`` Instead of reading it as a variable, it reads it as text. I cant put ` `around it because then it thinks the variable is all the text, not the output of the commands

Comment: @SkyScraper You meant if the input for `minPts` is not correct?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before finishing. And I am asking because I want to try the same for loop method as above to create multiple ggplots from the hdbscan_objects I made

Comment: @SkyScraper I guess you want to `get` the object, right?  then use `color = as.factor(get(paste0("hbdscan_object", i))[["cluster"]])`

Comment: Yes! exactly. Would you like me to make that a separate question for you to answer? ahh TYVM. Taught my get and taught me that I can call variables with [[ ]]. I am such a lost cause T-T

Comment: @SkyScraper it's okay.  Thank you for the comments